# iPhone memory leak monitoring when not hooked up to a computer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, memory-leaks

I have an application that needs to be unplugged from the computer to use (it is interfacing with a device through the port) so I don't think using Instruments will work. Is there any way to monitor memory allocations/leaks without the iPhone being attached to the computer? Thanks.

Comment: It is a good question, but nothing beats just going through your code and *understanding* where and why things may leak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use Instruments via WiFi instead of USB. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/releasenotes/General/RN-iPhoneSDK-3/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008407-CH1-SW17).
I never tried it, but it's a supported feature.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a jailbroken iOS device and analyze the app with the command line tool `leaks`. But that's not really a sweet solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Build and Analyze within Xcode? That will likely show many of your leaks without even needing to run the application.